# Why doesn't Lazyload show pictures?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-lazyload

I tried all the solution given on stackoverflow.

- [Jquery LazyLoad.js Issue with Loading after Window Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440233/jquery-lazyload-js-issue-with-loading-after-window-resize)
- [Lazy Load won't load visible images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419537/lazy-load-wont-load-visible-images)
- [jQuery LazyLoad do not load images until scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971151/jquery-lazyload-do-not-load-images-until-scroll)
- [LazyLoad images not appearing until after a scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535597/lazyload-images-not-appearing-until-after-a-scroll)

  ```
  Add a width height in css 
  Add a width height in HTML 
  $(window).resize(); 
  .trigger("lazyload");
  skip_invisible:true
  failure_limit : 1000
  ```

I also tried an alternative http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/

But the problem still the same. Unless I resize the window, (or $(window).resize(); in the console) picture don't show.
However, if I put a threshold of 300, the pictures in the 300 first pixels will appear, not the others...

The most strange is that the problem is the same for the 2 plugins.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Show us your code, which you are using

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue because your content, which contains the images, is loaded after the lazyload

Try calling lazyload in `setInterval` function or at the end of `window.load`.

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    $("img.lazy").lazyload();
    clearInterval(interval);
},1000);
```